# make a canvas in javafx look like it is light up

Tags: java, javafx, canvas, lighting

I have multiple canvases that represent indicator lights. They indicate wether a given function of the program is running or not. if it is running, the canvas should "light up" like a light source is emitting light through it. If the function is not active, the canvas should be "dark" as in not actively light up.

```
canvas.setEffect(new Lighting());
```

I tried javafx Lighting which gives nice results for the "not light up" stage, but i havent found a solution for actually lighting up the canvases.

Here is a picture of the canvases (in their default "not light up" stage) that i want to light:

[image: Canvas picture screenshot]

Comment: Could you post an image of the desired result of the same "field" when lit up and not? JavaFX light implementations only make sense in a 3D scene and canvas is 2D. However redrawing the "field" using different colors could solve your problem. Btw: `Canvas` imho is not the most conventient node type for this kind of layout. Personally I'd apply css to `ToggleButton`s to achieve this kind of look; this way you could update the look by simply changing the `selected` property of the `ToggleButton`...

Comment: Does `new Lighting(new Light.Point(65, 65, 100, Color.WHITE))` do the job any better?

Comment: There are other [effects](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/effect/package-summary.html) you can use singularly or in combination, which might be used to achieve the outcome you want.  Effects to consider are Bloom, Glow, ColorAdjust, Lighting, DropShadow.  You can use [SceneBuilder](https://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/) as a quick way to test out different effects and settings on nodes.

Comment: @VGR I used a value of 1000 for the z-compontent, works like a charm! thanks

Comment: @jewelsea bloom looks interesting, however in combination with the lighting it is too much. is there a way to control how much bloom gets added? the Bloom class only lets you control what pixels get the bloom effect added to them, you cant change the intesity of the bloom.

Comment: I don't think bloom is very configurable, you could try a [Glow](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/effect/Glow.html), which has an [intensity](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/effect/Glow.html#levelProperty) level setting.  Or adjust your lighting (e.g. use an orange or gray light rather than a white one), so that the Bloom+Lighting combination is more subtle.

Comment: @jewelsea with a bit of playing around you can indeed achieve the desired effect using lighting + glow. Thank you!

Comment: Cool, could you write up a [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and post it in the answer section, so that people know the exact settings you used to achieve the effect you wish (bonus points for a screenshot ;-). Hopefully StackOverflow lets you do that, it might require more reputation for that, but hopefully not.

Answer (score 2):

Using a Point Light did the trick for me. Canvas looks like it is light up. Like suggested below combining the lighting effect with different effects could lead to a even better result. I am happy the way it is now though.
Code i used:

```
Light.Point light = new Light.Point();
light.setX(65);
light.setY(65);
light.setZ(1000);
light.setColor(Color.WHITE);
Lighting lighting = new Lighting();
lighting.setLight(light);
canvas.setEffect(lighting);
```

Here is a picture displaying the off state (top icons) and the on state (bottom icons)
If you toggle the states, the difference is even more noticeable.

[image: Picture showing the effect]